# Counting permutations of multisets obtained from the prefix sum of certain integer arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multisets

Consider distinct arrangements of $k$ nonnegative integers that sum to $s$ with the the additional condition that the sum
of every other integer is $t \le s$. A bijective mapping of these arrangements to multisets is given by the prefix sum of
the first $k-1$ integers. What is the total number of permutations over all multisets thus obtained?

For example, when $k=4, s=3,$ and $t=2$, the mapping of arrangements to multisets is
\begin{pmatrix}
(2,1,0,0) & (2,0,0,1) & (1,1,1,0) & (1,0,1,1) & (0,1,2,0) & (0,0,2,1)\\
\{2,3,3\} & \{2,2,2\} & \{1,2,3\} & \{1,1,2\} & \{0,1,3\} & \{0,0,2\}
\end{pmatrix}
and the number of permutations over all multisets is $3+1+6+3+6+3=22$.

Comment: What does "the sum of every other integer" means?

Comment: "sum of every other integer" means sum of 1st, 3rd, 5th... integers

Comment: Cool. Have you tried something? Probably you have to control where to put $0'$s  in your arrangements.

Comment: Given an arrangement of $k$ integers, where the integers are equal to $0$ or $1$, we obtain a multiset as described above. The multinomial coefficient gives $m=$ the number of multiset permutations, which only depends on the locations of the zeros. The "stars and bars" method is used to get $n=$ the number of arrangements that sum to $s$ and $t$ subject to the constraints given by the locations of the zeros and that any integer equal to $1$ represents an integer $\ge 1$. The solution is given by the sum of $m \times n$ over all possible arrangements of zeros and ones.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not require enumeration.

Comment: "I am looking for a solution that does not require enumeration." Means that you want to explore a method different than yours? Is hard to tell if you solved the problem with the method described.

Comment: I should have been more clear. The problem is trivial if the locations of the zeros are known. The solution I described does work, but because of enumeration over all possible locations of the zeros, the maximum value of $k$ is limited to $\sim 45$. I am interested in a method where $k$ can be in the hundreds.